# Python' smtplib works regularly but not when executing via cron

Tags: python, smtplib

I have python code that looks like below. It works fine when executed manually. But when executed via a cronjob, the email is not being sent. Here is the code:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(login, password)
print mailServer.sendmail(login, to, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your environment in Unix is different when executed manually/from cron.Do a "env >file" in cron and compare to env when running interactively

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was `os.getenv` inside mailbody that didn't work.

Maybe the error occurs because cron script doesn't by default have any shell environment variables.